# tidyr - spread multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, spread

I'm preparing data for a network meta-analysis and I am having difficult in tyding the columns.

If I have this initial dataset:

```
Study Trt       y    sd   n
1       1   -1.22  3.70  54
1       3   -1.53  4.28  95
2       1   -0.30  4.40  76 
2       2   -2.60  4.30  71
2       4    -1.2   4.3  81
```

How can I finish with this other one?

```
Study Treatment1    y1  sd1  n1 Treatment2    y2  sd2  n2 Treatment3   y3 sd3 n3
    1     1          1 -1.22 3.70  54          3 -1.53 4.28  95         NA   NA  NA NA
    2     3          1 -0.30 4.40  76          2 -2.60 4.30  71          4 -1.2 4.3 81
```

I'm really stuck in this step, and I'd really appreciate some help...

Comment: I think your 'Treatment1' should be 1 1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can `gather` to 'long' format, then `unite` multiple columns to single and `spread` it to `wide`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, Var, Val,  Trt:n) %>%
      group_by(Study, Var) %>% 
      mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
      unite(VarT, Var, n, sep="") %>%
      spread(VarT, Val, fill=0)
```

Comment: It's much better! however I need to handly replace the zeros in the absent trt 3 for study 1?

Comment: @Juanchi  I guess you can remove the `fill=0` i.e. `spread(VarT, Val)`