# Spread [tidyr] with one key and multiple value columns

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr, spread

I am trying to use `spread` as part of the `tidyr` package. I have one `key` column (`structure_type`) and four `value` columns. (`structure_type` contains three factor levels.) All the documentation I've seen assumes that `spread` can only be used for one `key` column and one `value` column. But it seems like this should be possible to do this. Perhaps I should use the `reshape` library instead?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695424/tidyr-spread-multiple-columns) came close but I couldn't reproduce it.

```
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyr)
units_str_puma <- get_acs(geography = 'public use microdata area', table = "B25024",
                     state = c('OR', 'WA'))
units_str2_puma <- units_str_puma %>%
  mutate(structure_type = case_when(variable == "B25024_001" ~ "Total units",
                                    variable %in% c("B25024_002", "B25024_003") ~ "One-unit structure",
                                    TRUE ~ "Other")) %>%
  group_by(structure_type, GEOID) %>%
  summarize(units = sum(estimate),
            units_moe = moe_sum(moe = moe, estimate = estimate),
            units_cv = units_moe/1.645/units,
            units_cv_flag = case_when(units_cv > 0.4 ~ 1,
                                      TRUE ~ 0)) %>%
  spread(key=structure_type, value=c(units, units_moe, units_cv, units_cv_flag), drop=FALSE)
```

[image: Data structure]

Comment: Can you post some data in copy-and-pastaeble format? It appears that I'd need to sign up to access the data in your example.

Comment: I'm confused. (1) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272. (2) Please provide clear sample data for us to use, one example is `dput(head(x))` with just-enough variability to get your point across, other examples at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269. (3) Please provide clear expected output. Logically, I do not know what `spread`ing this type of data should look like post-expansion.

Comment: There are `data.table`  and `reshape` options that might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608167/reshape-multiple-value-columns-to-wide-format